# Could not initialize class magick.MagickImage

Tags: java, imagemagick

I am using magick API to convert cmyk image to RGB i have my code compiled without any errors but at runtime i am getting class not found type of exception plese help(i am doing the conversion in servlet). The code I have tried is attached below.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    MagickImage image = null;
       try {
    image = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo("D:\\1\\ftp\\cmyk.jpg"));
    image.rgbTransformImage(ColorspaceType.RGBColorspace);
            byte[] bytes =image.imageToBlob(new ImageInfo("D:\\1\\ftp\\cmyk.jpg"));
    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    } catch (MagickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

STACKTRACE:

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class magick.MagickImage
at servlet.ImageServlet.doGet(ImageServlet.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Well that suggests that you haven't included the library in your classpath... what have you tried in order to include it?

Comment: i included the jar in web-inf/lib folder and i can find the jar in .war also.

Comment: And which *exact* class can't be found? Please include the complete stack trace in your question. (Don't add it as a comment.)